MySQL - how to update one cell twice in one UPDATE SELECT statement?
The query is as follows:
UPDATE items, (VALUES ROW('sku1', 1), ROW('sku1', 2)) newavail          
    SET available = available + newavail.column_1`  
    WHERE items.sku = newavail.column_0;`

This query is supposed to add new arrival of goods to the warehouse. Sometimes, you have the same item shipped in multiple boxes, so you will add 'sku1' several times in one statement.
But, MySQL will not update the 'sku1' row more just once. The actual result is items.available will be +1, but expected is +3.
How can I modify the query to allow multiple modifications upon the same table cell?

Please provide a reference (link) to the kind of syntax you have for UPDATE.

The syntax is legit. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html

You did not answer my question. I asked specifically about UPDATE statement.  I'm not saying that it's wrong.

This is "update select" statement and it is in the title of this question.

@PM77-1, MySQL supports joins in UPDATE: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html This is non-standard SQL, but it works in MySQL.

I tested and it confirmed MySQL overwrites the value, instead of progressively adding to it.
I assume this is because of this in the manual:

If you access a column from the table to be updated in an expression, UPDATE uses the current value of the column.

In this case, the reference to available in the right-hand-side of the assignment is always based on the original value before the UPDATE.
SET available = available + newavail.column_1
                ^^^^^^^^^
                original value, not cumulative

I got your UPDATE to work in the following way, by summing the VALUES before making the assignment.
UPDATE items JOIN (
  SELECT sku, SUM(incoming) FROM (
    VALUES ROW('sku1', 1), ROW('sku1', 2)
  ) AS t(sku, incoming)
  GROUP BY sku
) AS newavail(sku, incoming) USING (sku)
SET available = available + newavail.incoming;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/mCWbjp7M
I also modified the syntax a bit, to show how to define column aliases for the derived table, and I used explicit JOIN...USING syntax.

I came to the same solution as this question looks like the limitation (design intent) of MySQL, as MySQL UPDATE doc says explicitly "Each matching row is updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times."
